# Add css fade in fade out in tooltip box

Tags: css, tooltip

I have a tooltip box and it is working fine. Now I want to add some fade in fade out once the tool-tip box pops in and out.

```
<a class="tooltip" title="This is some information for our tooltip." href="#"><img id="graph_one" alt="" src="https://www.onlandscape.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Doug-Chinnery-ICM-Images-4-45x45.jpg" class="graph one">  </a>
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/FHUbA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/Roobyx/FHUbA/45/

(you can fix the styles afterwards)

HTML:

```
<a class="has-tooltip" href="#">
    <span class="tooltip">This is some information for our tooltip.</span>
    <img id="graph_one" class="graph one" src="https://www.onlandscape.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Doug-Chinnery-ICM-Images-4-45x45.jpg" />  
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a[title].tooltip {
    width:45px;
    height:90px;
}

.tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.has-tooltip {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    margin: 150px 75px 10px 75px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* webkit flicker fix */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* webkit text rendering fix */
}

.has-tooltip .tooltip {
    background: #000;
    bottom: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    left: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
       -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
         -o-transform: translateY(10px);
            transform: translateY(10px);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
            transition: all .25s ease-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
       -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
        -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
         -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

.has-tooltip .tooltip:before {
    bottom: -20px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}  

.has-tooltip .tooltip:after {
    border-left: solid transparent 10px;
    border-right: solid transparent 10px;
    border-top: solid #000 10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -13px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}

.has-tooltip:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
       -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
         -o-transform: translateY(0px);
            transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate for replying late.That's really cool.Thanks.Answer accepted

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/FHUbA/14/

```
.tooltip:after{
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

background: #333;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 26px;
color: #fff;
content: attr(title);
left: 20%;
padding: 5px 15px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 98;
width: 220px;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```